# What trig identites were used in rewritting this equation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

The undamped response for a system is: $$x(t)=x(0)e^{-\zeta \omega t}(\cos \omega_d t+ \frac{\zeta}{\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}} \sin \omega_d t)$$

In the book they claimed using trig identities they were able to rewrite as $$\frac{x(0)}{\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}}e^{-\zeta\omega t} \cos \bigg( \omega_d t - \tan^{-1} \frac{\zeta}{\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}}\bigg)$$

I am not sure exactly which trig. identity to use that allows you to manipulated the equation this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important thing to note is that $\zeta$, $\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}$, and $1$ form the sides of a right angle triangle. Let $\theta$ be the angle between the sides of length $\sqrt{1-\zeta ^2}$ and $1$. Then
$$x(t)=x(0)e^{-\zeta \omega t}(\cos \omega_d t+ \frac{\zeta}{\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}} \sin \omega_d t)$$
$$=x(0)e^{-\zeta\omega t}(\cos \omega_d t +\tan \theta\sin \omega_dt)$$
$$=x(0)e^{-\zeta\omega t}\left(\frac{\cos \theta\cos\omega_dt+\sin\theta\sin\omega_dt}{\cos\theta}\right)$$
Using the difference identity for cosine gives
$$=x(0)e^{-\zeta\omega t}\left(\frac{\cos(\omega_dt-\theta)}{\cos\theta}\right)$$
Since $\cos\theta=\sqrt{1-\zeta ^2}$ and $\tan\theta=\frac{\zeta}{\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}}$, we have the desired equality
$$x(t)==x(0)e^{-\zeta\omega t}\left(\frac{\cos\left(\omega_dt-\tan^{-1}\frac{\zeta}{\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}}\right)}{\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}}\right)$$

Comment: I knew it had something to do with making a right triangle from $\zeta$ and 1. I just wasn't seeing it at the moment.

Comment: @adam Well that $\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}$ was pretty much a telltale sign.